# How to avoid extra information to be printed

Tags: perl

In my Perl code I have used the following line :

```
$host=$hostname if ($host eq undef);
```

In the output I am getting following message :

```
Use of uninitialized value $host in string eq at cli.pl line 18.
```

Though I am not using `strict`. How can I avoid this message to be print on output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`defined`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) function:

```
$host=$hostname if (!defined $host);
```

Or a shorter form:

```
$host=$hostname unless $host;
```

(And `use strict`, really.)

Comment: If it did help you, please consider reading this: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). It will help other people know that this question is solved.

Answer (score 2):

This operator may help: [defined-or operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#C-style-Logical-Defined-Or)

```
$host = $host // $hostname;
```

if `$host` is defined even its value is `''`,`0`,`'0'`, it will use `$host` as its value,
only if `$host` is `undef`, `$host` will get the `$hostname`'s value

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
$host //= $hostname;
```

// is the "defined or" operator. //= is its assignment version.